# Formatting hard drive

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive

I scavenged a hard drive for my currently lifeless 2009 Macbook Pro 13. The scavenged drive (from a 2010 white Macbook) had been working because it was taken to an electronics store to have its data transferred to a new computer.

I installed the drive, turned on the machine and got the question folder. Maybe they just stripped the drive of all of its data or perhaps the drive has failed. Is there a way for me to find out without spending too much money?

Comment: The DVD that shipped with Macs are tied to the hardware so that's why, among other things, I rewrote ctrebor's answer the way I did.  What resources do you have?  Do you have another working Mac. If you have another Mac you can download OS X 10.10 from the App Store, it's free, and create a USB Thumb-drive Installer that you can then boot the other Mac with and use Disk Utility and Terminal from it.  If you don't have another working Mac do you have a friend that has a Mac that you can create the USB Installer on?

Answer (score 2):

The MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2009) originally shipped with a Mac OS X 10.5.7 DVD and if you have the Mac OS X DVD that came with your system, or one that's compatible with your system, you can boot it from the Mac OS X DVD and see and test using Disk Utility and Terminal.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the DVD. The computer was purchased through my work place and I never received the DVD.